# Asset Management Solutions using Postgres

Tags: postgresql, assets

Not a technical question just looking for asset management software that uses postgreSQL for its back end. I tried a few but most of them seem to be geared towards IT Assets or Digital Assets. Tried openMAINT, which has some good features, but I would like to know what else is out there. It is for the Water and Waste Water Management Facilities and Infrastructure. Any suggestions? Would definitely be interested in open source.
Thanks for the help...

Comment: Not sure what the goal is, but chances are that non-technical questions may not get much traction here... Even at its non-technical merit... doubt I understand clearly what you mean by 'Asset Management' Software. Property Management as well as Financial Management are both assets per-say, but one is enterprise-y and the other personal finance of sorts...

Comment: Looking to track physical assets, history, condition, and manage work orders. So if I lookup asset X I can see its related assets work history date of commission/decommission and replacement asset. I want it in postgres so that the information can be passed to QGIS so that other workers can view and query the data without purchasing GIS Licenses. Did that clear it up some?